# retrive oath token and oauth secret from android twitter login using dialog

Tags: android, twitter

I'm making android login using twitter API 
the last step i made is to open this URL on dialog contains webview by this code

```
    @Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    String url = null;
    try {
        Log.i(TAG, "Retrieving request token from Google servers");
          url = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, Constants.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);
        Log.i(TAG, "Popping a browser with the authorize URL : " + url);



    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error during OAUth retrieve request token", e);
    }


    return url;
}
```

then i open the dialog with this URL and sign to twitter 
i need to make tweet and retrieve the username of the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [TwitterOAuthView](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/TwitterOAuthView) for getting accessToken.